# Android BLE readCharacteristic is false

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I'm trying to read message using Bluetooth low energy.
when (characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) == 0, the onCharacteristicRead will never be called. Now the characteristic.getProperties() = 16 and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ is 2, 2&16=0;
is there anyways to make (characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) != 0

If you know the way, please tell me it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey i am also facing same issue. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The peripheral decides what abilities the characteristic should have. You can't change that from the client side.